# IS possible to combine image and string in android studio

Tags: java, arrays, string

This the sample of the code. I want combine the image and string array.

`Question t1 = new Question (question: "image", option1: "A", option2: "B")`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var data = mutableListOf<Any>()

data.add("your image")
data.add("your string")
data.add("or any your type data")
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest will be a custom view with combination of ImageView and RadioButton inside of vertical LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:src="imageSrc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:text="A"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RadioButton
                android:text="B"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
```